# Pass entire macro input to another macro

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-decl-macros

I'm trying to make a simple macro that invokes `vec!` with whatever it receives then does some simple processing before returning the new vector:

```
macro_rules! sorted_vec {
    ($x:expr) => {
        {
            let v = vec![$x];
            v.sort();
            v
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that my macro is trying to parse the syntax, so it complains about commas, etc. That makes sense, but I'm not sure how to get around it. I don't think `expr` is the correct fragment specifier to use. How do I get it to pass the raw input on to `vec!` without processing it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fragment specifier you want is `tt` (Token-Tree). A `tt` is simply an arbitrary valid rust-token like a keyword or an operator or a bracket/block/square-bracket with arbitrary `tt`s inside. Combined with a variadic macro, you get infinite tokens that can be directly passed to another macro

```
macro_rules! sorted_vec {
    ($($x:tt)*) => {
        {
            let mut v = vec![$($x)*];
            v.sort();
            v
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess it's not "token type", it's ["token tree"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libsyntax/ext/tt/macro_parser.rs#L509), but I'm just nitpicking, of course :).

Comment: yea, I confused http://manishearth.github.io/rust-internals-docs/syntax/parse/parser/enum.TokenType.html with http://manishearth.github.io/rust-internals-docs/syntax/ast/enum.TokenTree.html ...